# How to know my DB user?

Tags: oracle, authentication

I use the PL-SQL developer tool. I  log in by using Prodcollops as user name to access the database. How can I find out if  my DB user is Prodcollops, too,  or if  it is just a login name?

Comment: I don't know what tool you're using, but can you log in as root/sysadmin? Then you should be able to view the users and roles and privileges and then do your work (*_not_* as root, normally). Paul...

Comment: I am using PL-SQL developer. I can log in using Prodcollops as user name to DB. But, i have the select rights only. I could not log in using SYSADMIN

Comment: `select user from dual` will tell you.

Comment: If you log in with the username "prodcollops", the database user will always be "prodcollops" so the question doesn't make a great deal of sense.  What sort of distinction are you trying to make between a "database user" and a "login name"?

Answer (score 1):

As  @a_horse_with_no_name stated in a comment, there is a function `USER` that returns the user of a session, so

```
select USER from DUAL
```

is a way to find out the user of a session.